# Redefining enum enumerators with #define

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor

I have spotted something in **C** header files what I can't figure out what is for. For example in file `bits/socket.h` there is an enumeration type  `enum __socket_type`, but after every enumerator there is a define macro which defines the same. Example:

```
enum __socket_type
{
   SOCK_STREAM = 1,
   #define SOCK_STREAM SOCK_STREAM 
   ...
};
```

I have been unable to find out what this is for. Please enlighten me. I don't even know how to form right question  for querying google nor this site search box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A prepreprocessor macro will never expand recursively, so what such a `#define` does is leave the name in place whereever it is used. Such things are useful when you want to have a preprocessor feature test.

```
#ifdef SOCK_STREAM
..
#endif
```

can be used to conditionally compile some code afterwards.

**Edit:** So this combines the cleaner approach of enumerations (implicit values without collisions and scoping) with preprocessor tests.

Comment: indeed, this makes sense, but why there are also enums not only defines?

Comment: I was afraid that you will say this. :P Doing such "universal" things often makes my programming life harder...

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I can think of is because people see a constant in all-caps, say `NUM_FILES`, they'll think it's a macro and are tempted to write this:

```
#ifdef NUM_FILES
```

Now normally this would fail, but if you write `#define NUM_FILES NUM_FILES` it behaves as a macro for the preprocessor and IDE's and as an enum for the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it's for IDEs or other tools to understand that a symbol is defined in some way.