# What does the #define ROBJECT_EMBED_LEN_MAX ROBJECT_EMBED_LEN_MAX do?

Tags: c, ruby, mri

Browsing through MRI's code, I found these `#define`s I don't understand:

```
#define ROBJECT_EMBED_LEN_MAX ROBJECT_EMBED_LEN_MAX
#define ROBJECT_EMBED ROBJECT_EMBED
enum {
    ROBJECT_EMBED_LEN_MAX = 3,
    ROBJECT_EMBED = RUBY_FL_USER1,

    ROBJECT_ENUM_END
};
```

What's the point of those `#define`s? They seem to do nothing...

This code is found in the `ruby/include/ruby/ruby.h` file in the ruby github repo.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara No, it's not, this define seems to be referencing the enum.

Comment: It's not a multi-line macro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685211/c-define-multiline-macro

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6830602

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redefining enum enumerators with #define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830602/redefining-enum-enumerators-with-define)

Answer (score 0):

The `#define`s make it possible to test for the existence of the definition at compile-time using `#ifdef`. (You cannot test for the existence of an enum at compile-time.)

Since the C preprocessor doesn't do recursive substitution, defining a symbol as itself effectively does nothing; the symbol is replaced once with itself, and then passed normally to the compiler.